# Can a Pi3 be used as an RS232 to TTL Level Shifter?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+

I have a couple of Pi 3's here, and have to recover an Iomega NAS.  Normally I would use a USB device and have the cables connected from a laptop, run up putty, communicate over the usb serial port to access its bootloader.

Can i streamline this a bit by connecting it to the pins on the pi?, and then VNC in and terminal in using the pi?

Comment: The pi Can probably use the usb serial device

Answer (score 0):

"Can a Pi3 be used as an RS232 to TTL Level Shifter?" **NO**!

If you want to connect to RS232 (even the fake RS232 used by most devices) you NEED a converter module. RS232 uses inverse signalling to the Pi serial port and generally higher voltage levels.